# GAE: Soft limit exceeded when loading lots of big files python

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have a problem with GAE and python:

I've overtaken a survey tool for my university that fulfills some tasks - one of it is that it tracks the mouse cursor movements.

When the survey finishes, the data is being submitted to the controller which stores it in the blobstore, as the results can become slightly bigger than 1 MB which if off the quota.

Now, I need to export it into an excel file and I wanted to used XLWT for it. I tried using it via a task queue, which gets executed.

On small datasets, all is fine. But after approx. 10-12 datasets I reach the memory soft limit. 
I already tried to run garbage collection tasks and so on so that memory gets cleared.

Is there any possibility combine all data (approx. 300*~1.5 MB) and serve it as an excel file?

I already opened a stream to write the excel file in the blobstore but the error persists.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to read the [Python Excel tutorial](http://www.simplistix.co.uk/presentations/python-excel.pdf). See also the page http://www.python-excel.org/. There they suggest to call flush_row_data on the worksheet.

Any way, combining 300 (1.5Mb) files is most likely not possible using a F1 instance, as the memory is 128MB and XLWT holds the temp data in a tempfile, whihc in GAE is just a StringIO object.

Consider using dynamic backends for this and using a B4_1G instance.

Also, is there any reason not to genereate a CSV.